# Android Application onLowMemory() on API >= 14

Tags: android, performance

a tiny question.

According to the `Android` docs:

> Preferably, you should implement ComponentCallbacks2.onTrimMemory from ComponentCallbacks2 to incrementally unload your resources based on various levels of memory demands. That API is available for API level 14 and higher, so you should only use this onLowMemory method as a fallback for older versions

So. Will `onLowMemory()` be called by higher API's as well?
Clearly, I just want to call it from within `onTrimMemory()` when the level is `TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE`, but I don't want it to be called twice :)

Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. It is not deprecated at any API level. You should be implementing both `onTrimMemory()` and `onLowMemory()` for the sake of keeping the system healthy.

These are covered in more detail in the video: [Trimming and Sharing Memory (Android Performance Patterns Season 3 ep5)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8Hddx1eOZo&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&index=5).

Comment: So the one method I will actually implement is the OLD one:)

Comment: Really, you should be implementing both onTrimMemory and onLowMemory for the sake of keeping the system healthy. These are covered in more detail here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8Hddx1eOZo&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&index=5

Comment: @ColtMcAnlis Is that really you from YouTube videos? You are great)